# How to deploy a telegram bot developed with python-telegram-bot on azure

Tags: deployment, azure-functions, python-telegram-bot

I developed a telegram bot using the popular python-telegram-bot library in python.

The bot is a simple echo bot, you can find at this tutorial:
https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/echobot.py

Is it possible to deploy it on a serverless architecture, like an Azure Function?

Comment: How's going? Has your issue got solved ?

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy your python bot to Azure functions. The link below will be helpful for you :

[Creating a Serverless Python Chatbot API in Microsoft Azure from Scratch in 9 Easy Steps](https://towardsdatascience.com/creating-a-serverless-python-chatbot-api-in-microsoft-azure-from-scratch-in-9-easy-steps-2f1913fc9581)

Comment: Thank you. However this link provide the explanation for the deployment using the MS Bot Framework. I only used the python-telegram-bot library